# Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with many proposal distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains

Suppose we wanted to sample elements according to a distribution $P(x)$. The Metropolis-Hastings (MH) method is to just draw a proposed new value $x^*$ from a (not necessarily symmetric) proposal distribution function $f(x^* | x_i)$ and decide wether to accept it or not with an acceptance ratio $q = \frac{f(x_i | x^*)}{f(x^* | x_i)} \frac{P(x^*)}{P(x_i)}$.

My question is, could we use, say, two proposal distribution functions? What I mean is the following:

We start with a value $x_0$, then we draw a proposed value $x^*$ with the distribution $f$. We calculate the acceptance ratio as $q_f = \frac{f(x_0 | x^*)}{f(x^* | x_0)} \frac{P(x^*)}{P(x_i)}$ and get a new value $x_1$ (that is going to be either $x^*$ or $x_0$ based on wether we accept $x^*$ or not). We plug $x_1$ in a different proposal distribution function $g$ and get a proposed new value $x^{**}$. We calculate the acceptance ratio as: $q_g = \frac{g(x_1 | x^*)}{g(x^* | x_1)} \frac{P(x^*)}{P(x_1)}$ and we get a new value $x_2$. Then we start over.

Would this or a similar variant work?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are suggesting that successive iterations of the algorithm alternate between different proposal distributions; i.e., for all odd iterations we use proposal $f$, and for all even iterations we use proposal $g$.  I imagine (but have no proof) that if MH converges in each case using $f$ or $g$ alone, it should converge for your alternating case.  But I wonder to what end; i.e., what purpose does it serve?

Comment: I had mainly two things in mind: what if instead of real numbers I was sampling on more complicated objects, then it might not be easy to find a proposal distribution function $f$ that can cover well all this space, but maybe two could. The second reason was just personal curiosity.